# how to put PostgreSQL project/scripts under Azure DevOps

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, azure-devops, devops

We Are planning on using PostgreSQL to replace SQL Server for our in house applications.

SQL Server has the option to create a database project under Visual studio and manage the changes under Azure DevOps.

I can't seem to find a way to do the same with PostgreSQL, there no project type and no clear path on how to host the project/files under Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use JavaScript on Azure PostgreSQL
As a newbie, I apologize if my answer was not appropriate.
Indeed to create or move your PostgreSQL database to Azure, you need a PostgreSQL resource.

Develop a JavaScript application with PostgreSQL on Azure
To create, move, or use a PostgreSQL database to Azure, you need an Azure Database for PostgreSQL server resource. Learn how to create the resource and use your database.

Create an Azure Database for PostgreSQL resource
Create a resource with:
Azure CLI command = az postgres server create
Visual Studio Code
Azure portal

View and use your PostgreSQL server on Azure
While developing your PostgreSQL database with JavaScript, use one of the following tools:

Azure Cloud Shell - psql CLI is available
pgAdmin
Visual Studio Code extension
Use SDK packages to develop your PostgreSQL server on Azure
The Azure PostgreSQL uses npm packages already available, such as:

pg
Use pg SDK to connect to PostgreSQL on Azure
To connect and use your PostgreSQL on Azure with JavaScript, use the following procedure.

Make sure Node.js and npm are installed.

Create a Node.js project in a new folder:

```
mkdir DbDemo && \
    cd DbDemo && \
    npm init -y && \
    npm install pg && \
    touch index.js && \
    code .
```

The command:

Creates a project folder named DbDemo
Changes the Bash terminal into that folder
Initializes the project, which creates the package.json file
Installs the pg npm package - to use async/await
Creates the index.js script file
Opens the project in Visual Studio Code
Copy the following JavaScript code into index.js:

:::code language="JavaScript" source="~/../js-e2e/database/postgresql/index.js" :::

Replace the YOUR-ADMIN-USER, YOURRESOURCENAME, and YOUR-PASSWORD with your values in the script for your connection string.

Run the script to connect to the postgres server and see the base tables and users.

```
node index.js
```

View the results.

```
[
  { table_name: 'pg_statistic' },
  { table_name: 'pg_type' },
  { table_name: 'pg_authid' },
  { table_name: 'pg_user_mapping' },
  { table_name: 'pg_attribute' },
  { table_name: 'pg_proc' },
  { table_name: 'pg_class' },
  { table_name: 'pg_attrdef' },
  { table_name: 'pg_constraint' },
  { table_name: 'pg_inherits' },
  { table_name: 'pg_index' },
  { table_name: 'pg_operator' },
  { table_name: 'pg_opfamily' },
  { table_name: 'pg_opclass' },
  { table_name: 'pg_am' },
  { table_name: 'pg_amop' },
  { table_name: 'pg_amproc' },
  { table_name: 'pg_language' },
  { table_name: 'pg_largeobject_metadata' },
  { table_name: 'pg_aggregate' },
  { table_name: 'pg_rewrite' },
  { table_name: 'pg_largeobject' },
  { table_name: 'pg_trigger' },
  { table_name: 'pg_event_trigger' },
  { table_name: 'pg_description' },
  { table_name: 'pg_cast' },
  { table_name: 'pg_enum' },
  { table_name: 'pg_namespace' },
  { table_name: 'pg_conversion' },
  { table_name: 'pg_depend' },
  { table_name: 'pg_database' },
  { table_name: 'pg_db_role_setting' },
  { table_name: 'pg_tablespace' },
  { table_name: 'pg_pltemplate' },
  { table_name: 'pg_auth_members' },
  { table_name: 'pg_shdepend' },
  { table_name: 'pg_shdescription' },
  { table_name: 'pg_ts_config' },
  { table_name: 'pg_ts_config_map' },
  { table_name: 'pg_ts_dict' },
  { table_name: 'pg_ts_parser' },
  { table_name: 'pg_ts_template' },
  { table_name: 'pg_extension' },
  { table_name: 'pg_foreign_data_wrapper' },
  { table_name: 'pg_foreign_server' },
  { table_name: 'pg_foreign_table' },
  { table_name: 'pg_policy' },
  { table_name: 'pg_replication_origin' },
  { table_name: 'pg_default_acl' },
  { table_name: 'pg_init_privs' },
  { table_name: 'pg_seclabel' },
  { table_name: 'pg_shseclabel' },
  { table_name: 'pg_collation' },
  { table_name: 'pg_range' },
  { table_name: 'pg_transform' },
  { table_name: 'sql_features' },
  { table_name: 'sql_implementation_info' },
  { table_name: 'sql_languages' },
  { table_name: 'sql_packages' },
  { table_name: 'sql_parts' },
  { table_name: 'sql_sizing' },
  { table_name: 'sql_sizing_profiles' }
]
[ { usename: 'azure_superuser' }, { usename: 'YOUR-ADMIN-USER' } ]
done
```